# How to read and write a text file in ActionScript 2.0 (Macromedia Flash 8)

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, flashdevelop, macromedia

I'm making some Animation project with Macromedia Flash 8, which uses ActionScript 2.0. I need some simple options like to save user to text file and read it. But, I couldn't find about writing to text file. Found some code that reads, but not writes.
 
**Example of reading:**

```
loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.onData = function(raw) {
    myField.text = raw;
}
loadText.load("user.txt");
```

Can someone help me, with examples of writing, parsing read data. Shortly, Working External data. 
I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: You won't be able to save the text with Flash 8 alone, unless you use a serverside script to write the file. Another approach however is using a local [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001504.html#462090). It's kind of like a cookie, but for Flash Player. This should allow to read/write text on a client's computer, however, not in a text file. You could use a free opensource IDE like [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org) to create an actionscript 3 implementation using the FileReference class

Comment: Thanks man. It's cool. I'm searching it about a 2 weeks, couldn't find. You gave a way

Comment: no worries, glad it helps. Also check [this](http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/) out. You should be able to tap into that via [Externalinterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001039.html).Not sure it works in all browsers though